# ASCII biggest number value

Tags: c

When I hold values bigger than 255 (decimal) and print the ASCII character, the program prints some characters. Why? 254 isn't the biggest number in ASCII? Same thing happen when I hold negative numbers (eg: -6), but is not working for -1 and 0. Why?

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to use this in any "real" code, but especially if you're just learning C now I think that it's great that you're exploring the limits of the language, figuring out not only what's possible but also why.

Answer (score 6):

What happens depends on your machine.

Values that go beyond the maximum representable usually wrap around. So, for example, if you hold 256, it will wrap around to 0, 257 will give you 1, etc, or, if your machine uses signed characters, instead of 256, max value will be 127, and 128 wraps around to the most negative value (that is, -128 with 8 bit characters, assuming a 2's complement representation). If these values happen to represent a valid printable character, then that's what you get.

Note that it is generally not safe to assume that overflowed values wrap around: the C standard doesn't require this to happen, so, technically, a program relying on that trick has undefined behavior.

Comment: Setting 8-bit char to 256 would wrap to 0, not -128.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior, and the exact result will depend on some combination of your programing language/compiler/computer etc. Sometimes you'll get an exception or crash, and sometimes you'll get a character. In the case of the character, what you're most likely seeing is an overflow. The standard char type is a single byte, made of 8 bits that can be 0 or 1. The details will vary depending on your system, but what happens is something like this:

You try to assign 256, the binary representation of which looks like this:

```
 1 0000 0000 (a one with 8 zeros)
```

to a char, which can only hold 8 bits. Thus, the first bit gets truncated, leaving you with this:

```
 0000 0000 (8 zeros)
```

which is equivalent to the value 0. So, if your system happens to work like I described you'd end up printing out whatever ascii character is associated with the value 0. There are a couple of different ways the above can play out depending on system details like endianness.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `%c` to print a character, it will access `1byte` print the content of that `1byte`. Maximum `unsigned` numbers that can be represented using `8bits` = `1byte` is `255` `(0 to (2pow(8-1))-1)` i.e `0 to 255`

i.e from

```
0000 0000
```

to

```
1111 1111
```

When you try to print 257 in binary (`1 0000 0001`) using %c, it will see only `1 byte` i.e `0000 0001`. Corresponding character for `0000 0001` is printed.